# MediaPlayer error (-4, -4)

Tags: android

i play video from URL. 1st i put video on local server and it's run in device. client put video on https://s3.amazonaws.com server. now when i play video it's not play. this is logcat:

```
03-16 12:07:20.244: D/MediaPlayer(5099): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
03-16 12:07:20.289: W/MediaPlayer(5099): info/warning (1, 26)
03-16 12:07:20.294: E/MediaPlayer(5099): error (-4, -4)
03-16 12:07:20.309: I/MediaPlayer(5099): Info (1,26)
03-16 12:07:20.314: E/MediaPlayer(5099): Error (-4,-4)
03-16 12:07:20.314: D/VideoView(5099): Error: -4,-4
```

i dnt knw what is issue. video convert from this formats http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Becuase HTTPS video streaming is not supported before Android 3.1. Refer your link and search for **Network Protocols**. If you are  not using API level lower than Android 3.1's API level use **http** instead of **https** your video will playback properly.